# Update button array in jpanel

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, updatepanel

I send a array of int to constructor panel, in the first time this create the gui, but with the next array no update the panel/jframe.

```
class panel extends JPanel{

    public panel(int matriz[][]) {

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
        this.revalidate();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if(matriz[i][j]==1)
                {

                    JButton boton = new JButton("");   
                    boton.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                    this.add(boton);
                    boton.revalidate();
                    boton.repaint();

                }
                else
                {
                    JButton boton = new JButton("");   
                    this.add(boton);
                    boton.revalidate();
                    boton.repaint();
                }

                if(j==4) //imprimo pa ver si realmente me esta enviando datos desde creandoVida
                    System.out.println("n"+matriz[i][j]);
                else
                    System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);

            }
        }

        System.out.println("---");
        this.doLayout();
        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.revalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell what you are doing based on the code posted. But some general comments:

1. You only need to do revalidate() and repaint() once AFTER all the components have been created and added to the panel. So those two statements should be OUTSIDE the for loop
2. Don't invoke revalidate() from within the paintComponent() method. That may cause an infinite loop since many time a revalidate() will invoke repaint() again. I see no reason for you to override the paintComponent() method at all.
3. Use Java naming conventions. Class names start with an upper case character. But don't call your class "Panel" since there already is an AWT class of the name.

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Edit:

Actually I see that you are creating a completely new panel, so none of the revalidate(), repaint() logic is needed in this class.

Once you create the "panel" you must add the panel to the frame and then revalidate the frame. Otherwise all you are doing is creating a panel that sits in memory doing nothing. So the code that creates this panel is responsible for adding the panel to the frame. Since you didn't post that code I can't tell what you are doing.

Comment: thx, i update the code, but the problem persists. "matriz" have the new data but the jpanel no change absolutely

Comment: @user3547063, see edit. Without a Proper `SSCCE`, I can't offer any more help.